# Traversing element from 1 to n less than O(n)

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o

How to traverse from 1 to n in less than O(n).

eg.

```
arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

We want to print:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 less than O(n) or O(n/2)
```

Comment: it is impossible

Comment: btw, O(N) and O(N/2) is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since to print the *n* elements, you'll have to touch each element at least once, @IlyaBursov has correctly mentioned in the comment that it is impossible.

---

**Important Disclaimer:**

I feel silly to add anything more in an answer to this question. The points below are related to another topic. They demo other ways to think about solving a problem and not attempt to convert an impossibility into a possibility.

---

That being said, what you can do is that you can divide the work among multiple threads, especially if it is not important to print them in order, and have the task processed in parallel.

This will cut down your *execution time* from O(n) to O(n/k) where *k* is the number of parallel processes you have started, assuming:

1. You have at least *k* cores free; and,
2. n > k.

However, total work you did in this case is still:

> = O(n/k) work per thread * k threads
>
> = O((n/k) * k)
>
> = O(n)

---

**A caveat regarding mutli-threading:**

If you are going to start threads when you get the task, it will add extra execution time. So you need to have the threads running in a pool and then assign them the part of the array they have to process.

If you repeat this process a high enough number of times, then the cost of creating the the *k* threads first time will be amortized and be totally offset.

Comment: It is also possible to do it in N/2
eg for(i = 1;i<=N/2;i++){
          cout<<i<<i+1;
          cout<<N-i<<N-(i+1);
     }

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible for the simple reason that printing a total of k characters requires you to do at least k work, and there are at least n characters to be printed when listing out the values from 1 to n, inclusive.

(In fact, there are Θ(n log n) characters, since the number of characters needed to write the number n in some fixed base is Θ(log n)).

Comment: Can you expand on - "the number of characters needed to write the number n in some fixed base is Θ(log n)"?

Comment: Sure! When we write numbers out using place values, each digit represents an exponentially larger quantity. In that sense, in some fixed base (say, base 10), we have a relation where a number n relates to its number of digits d roughly as n ~ 10^d. Solving for d, we get that d ~ log_10 n.

Comment: This is not quite right, the base is a given and does not vary based on the size of the list. You could say that its Θ(n log max(arr)) however assuming unbounded variable size

Comment: I thought the question was specifically about printing an array of the values 1 through n - did I misread the OP?